# Preg_replace и функция

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется страница, ну на пример где есть в разных областях html кода цифры в разных количествах. Я вызываю на это странице `ob_start(getu);` функция имеет следующее тело:

```
function getu($buffer) {
$buffer = preg_replace("/([0-9]){4,}/","<span>".cval($0)."</span>",$buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

пытался по разному, но так и не получилось вставить найденное совпадение и вставить в функцию как параметр. если запустить функцию так как она щас есть выдаст ошибку о символе $, если вставлю его в ковычки, то функция не выполнится, выведется просто число. если же делаю соединение строки ."$0". выдаёт ошибку типа лишняя . или )

без функции `"<span>$0</span>"` выводится. если сделать `"<span>".cval(123456)."</span>"` то всё работает. А мне нужно вставить туда именно найденное число. Как с этим разбираться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял, вам нужна вот эта функция.
[preg-replace-callback](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: Видимо что-то не так делаете:

    $buffer= preg_replace("/([0-9]){4,}/", function($match) {
         return "<span>".cval($match[0])."</span>";
    },$buffer);

Comment: http://ideone.com/5nMKfC

Comment: Покажите ваш код. я ссылку скинул, где написал пример, и он работает.

Comment: Если ошибка на моем примере, то это из-за старой версии пхп. Видимо используете версию, которая без анонимных функций.